# Trying to setup a 2 way file sync in Linux

Tags: filesystems, rsync, replication

I am trying to setup a 2 way file sync in linux of reasonably small data-set. I would like to replicate data over WAN so distributed filesystems like gluster are not in point of my interest - they are slow (especially reads of lots and small files like php applications). Gluster performance with that kind of storage is awful. And I want use this replication for a webapp hosting solution).

I know some mechanisms like lsyncd, incron, the inotify, and ofcource rsync or unison but it is hard to tie them togoether. The hardest part is when there is a bidirectional sync then because of notify systems im sending same files in both directions:

**A**(new files, notified) ---rsync----> **B**(not new files, but inotify doesnt know so also notifies)

**B** ---rsync same files ---->  **A**

I tried to organize the rsyncs between hosts using a FIFO manner to synchronize but it still isnt the best way because the fifo grows large because of each file notification(like 1000new files = 1000 notification) and those notification are mixed in FIFO from 2 hosts so I cant actually batch them togoether. Most cleanest solution would be to try somehow dig in inotify/lsyncd and make them know that when the monitoring filesystems receive data from rsync or over ssh protocol then it **shouldnt** send a notify, and when an apache or proftpd is writing then it **should** send a notify. Having this a simple replication-controller with FIFO for rsyncs and some locking/load distribution system would be good enough to make a reliable 2 way sync solution

Have anyone ever tried to make something like this?

Comment: Have you considered mounting the filesystem over the network? This would eliminate the replication problems.

Comment: NFS is terrible and I want replicate data between 2 dedicated server. NFS with its performance on slow bandwidth network would kill my webapps,

Comment: You can look at osync - (https://github.com/deajan/osync). I use it and found it to be helpful.

Comment: RAID 1 over NBD with "read mostly" on the local half of the mirror? OCFS2? If it's a relatively small dataset why couldn't `unison` work for you?

Comment: @roaima problem with unison is that it doesnt have option of automatic triggering. And I couldnt setup it with lsyncd.

Comment: You are looking for a distributed filesystem. That's what instant replication is. You didn't manage to cobble something together because it just isn't something you can cobble together, it's complex. What should happen if the file is created on both sides at the same time? That alone is a huge problem. Use a distributed filesystem where people have spent years to get replication working.

Comment: @Gilles 

I would like to use distrubuted filesystem but over wan the read times are very slow. Especially for webapplications which have a lot but small files. I.e GlusterFS readtimes over a WAN with about 100mbit bandwidth between 2 nodes is slow as hell.